# FilePathField makes backslashes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I use `FilePathField` in Django but the paths are operative system specific. When I use it on Windows I get backslashes in my paths.

```
image = models.FilePathField(path='static/img')
```

This seems to be a bug? How can I avoid it? A bad solution would be to replace backslashes in the template with normal slashes. But how? And can I find other options?

## Edit

I can choose between all files in my `static/img` directory. Now I want to print the file path in my templates with: `{{ object.image }}` but it results in `static/img\chosen_file.png`. Html and CSS can't interpret the backslashes as forward slashes so `background-image: url({{ object.image }});` doesn't point correctly to the image file.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what is happening, and why you think this is a problem. Please post an example of the output, and explain exactly what issues this is causing.

Comment: How is the field value being assigned?

Comment: In a plain `UpdateView`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just has the same problem and the simple answer is: Add a trailing slash to the path.

```
image = models.FilePathField(path='static/img/')
```

Worked for me on Windows 7 with Django 1.9.2 and Python 3.4.2.

But: only works for files directly in the folder, not sub-folders